# PHP: Uploading public files to a folder inside a Google storage bucket

Tags: php, laravel, google-api, google-cloud-storage

Sorry for the noob question but this is a problem I can't seem to crack. I have a laravel script to upload file publicly to a google storage bucket and it is working properly. The problem is that object that I upload is just inside the bucket, where it should be placed inside a directory inside the bucket. e.g bucket - /dev-bucket/ , correct directory - /dev-bucket/media/ below is my script

```
            $client = new \Google_Client();
            $credential = new \Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            'xxxxxx@appspot.gserviceaccount.com',
            ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control'],
            file_get_contents(storage_path().'xxxxx.p12')
        );
        $client->setAssertionCredentials($credential);

        // this access control is for project owners
        $ownerAccess = new \Google_Service_Storage_ObjectAccessControl();
        $ownerAccess->setEntity('project-owners-' . 'xxxxxxxxxxx');
        $ownerAccess->setRole('OWNER');

        // this access control is for public access
        $readerAccess = new \Google_Service_Storage_ObjectAccessControl();
        $readerAccess->setEntity('allUsers');
        $readerAccess->setRole('READER');

        $storage = new \Google_Service_Storage($client);
        $obj = new \Google_Service_Storage_StorageObject();
        $obj->setName($stageFileName);
        $obj->setAcl([$ownerAccess, $readerAccess]);

        $storage->objects->insert(
            Config::get('constants.bucket'),
            $obj,
            [
                'name'          => $stageFileName,
                'data'          => file_get_contents($stageFile),
                'uploadType'    => 'media',
            ]
        );
```

Is there an option on how to put the object inside the directory inside the bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to upload files in the directory by pre-pending the file name of the object to be uploaded with the directory in the bucket for uploading. For example if you have a directory in your bucket called dev your filename should start with 'dev/{fileToBeUploaded}.txt'

Comment: Thanks so much. I've looking for this everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

To upload a file to a specific folder in google bucket, I wrote below code:

```
Blob blob=
storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(bucketName,"folder_name/"+f.getName()).setAcl(acls).build(),f.getInputStream());
```

And for downloading from that folder:

```
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(bucketName, vendorName+"/"+fileName);
Blob blob = storage.get(blobId);
```

P.S. This is in JAVA, can do similar stuff in any other language.